# ZIO: How to join Fibers for Processes that run forever

Tags: scala, concurrency, functional-programming, for-comprehension, zio

I have the following ZIO program with two processes that both run forever:

```
    for {
      ..
      numberProvider <- numberProvider(queue).fork  // runs forever
      numberService <- numberService(queue)         // runs forever
      ..
    } yield ()
```

The above code works, but I was wondering if this is good practice.

There are 2 questions:

1. Is it ok, to run the 2. process on the main program. Or should it be also a *Fiber*?
2. Do I have to `join` the Fibers in the end, even if they run forever and therefore never reach the `join`?

   ```
   for {
     ..
     numberProvider <- numberProvider(queue).fork  // runs forever
     numberService <- numberService(queue)         // runs forever
     ..
     _ <- numberProvider.join // join in any case
   } yield ()
   ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you don't have to `.join` fiber if they run forever.

Note that since `1.0.0-RC17`, #zio added the `.daemon` combinator for exactly that reason, see release note here: https://github.com/zio/zio/releases/tag/v1.0.0-RC17 and that from now on, `.fork` should be avoided for forever-running fibers.

Answer (score 1):

From the answer of *fanf42* I adjusted my code to:

```
for {
      ..
      numberProvider <- numberProvider(queue).daemon  // runs forever
      numberService <- numberService(queue)           // runs forever
      ..
    } yield ()
```

But this did not work (changed `fork` to `daemon`). It never got to the next line.

So make sure to `fork` the `daemon` as well.

```
for {
      ..
      numberProvider <- numberProvider(queue).daemon.fork  // runs forever
      numberService <- numberService(queue)                // runs forever
      ..
    } yield ()
```